# Is it possible to pass arguments to the class and the parent class constructor?

Tags: php

```
Class a {
        public function __construct($a){
                $this->age = $a;
        }
}

Class b extends a {
        public function printInfo(){
                echo 'age: ' . $this->age . "\n";
        }
}

$var = new b('age');
$var->printInfo();
```

I understand how this code works, however is it possible to pass arguments to the constructor of the class and parent class?

My attempt below is causing an error

```
Class a {
        public function __construct($a){
                $this->age = $a;
        }
}

Class b extends a {
        public function __construct($name){
                $this->name = $name;
        }
        public function printInfo(){
                echo 'name: ' . $this->name . "\n";
                echo 'age: ' . $this->age . "\n";
        }
}

$var = new b('name', 'age');
$var->printInfo();
?>
```

Comment: `parent::__construct();` in class b will call the constructor in class a. So try `public function __construct($name, $age){ $this->name = $name; parent::__construct($age); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to use the `parent::__construct()` method.

Like so:

```
class a{        

    /**
     * The age of the user
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $age;

    function __construct($a){
        $this->age = $a;
    }

}

class b extends a{        

    /**
     * The name of the user
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    function __construct($name,$age){
        // Set the name
        $this->name = $name;

        // Set the age
        parent::__construct($age);
    }

    public function printInfo(){
        echo 'name: ' . $this->name . "\n";
        echo 'age: ' . $this->age . "\n";
    }
}

$var = new b('name','age');
$var->printInfo();
```

***Just make sure the variables are set to public or protected!***

Comment: it's a bad idea to override methods giving them different method signatures. `public function __construct($args = array()) { parent::__construct($args); }` is an example avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to the parent constructor but the way you are doing is wrong,

```
$var = new b('name', 'age');
```

it is as if the child class accepts two parameters in its constructor but in real it has only one parameter.

You can pass parameter to parent constructor something like this

```
parent::__construct($var);
```

So change you class b to this

```
Class b extends a {
    public function __construct($name, $age){
            $this->name = $name;
            parent::__construct($age);
    }
    public function printInfo(){
            echo 'name: ' . $this->name . "\n";
            echo 'age: ' . $this->age . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass the argument to the class as well as parent class

```
Class a {
        public function __construct($age){
                $this->age = $a;
        }
}

Class b extends a {
        public function __construct($name,$age){
                parent::__construct($age);
                $this->name = $name;
        }      
}

$var = new b('name', 'age');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call parent::__construct in the child. for example

```
class Form extends Tag
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Called second.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how is should go:

```
<?php
class a {
    private $age;
    public function __construct($age){
            $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    private $name;

    public function __construct($age, $name){
        parent::__construct($age);
            $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function printInfo(){
            echo 'name: ' . $this->name . "\n";
            echo 'age: ' . $this->getAge() . "\n";
    }
}

$b = new b(20, "Bob");
$b->printInfo();
?>
```